# codeigniter assigning values got from model to variables in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use Codeigniter and I want to return user_id and name from model and then use them as variables in controller but not sure if I correctly values to variables in controller. Could you please have a look at my code.

model:

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {            
    $row = $query->row();
    return array('user_id' => $row->user_id, 'name' => $row->name);
}
```

controller:

```
$user_id = $this->model_users->get_user_id_name($email);
$user_name = $this->model_users->get_user_id_name($email);
```

Comment: Your model coding is correct however in controller why are you calling two times'. In your model its returning an array. Just call one time and it will give you one array. And from this array you can get user_id as well name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an associative array from model , 
catch it in controller as

```
$userinfo = $this->model_users->get_user_id_name($email);
```

$user_id =  $userinfo['userid']; 
$user_name =  $userinfo['name'];

If in case you want to return a indexed array , pass it as

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {            
    $row = $query->row();
    return array( $row->user_id,  $row->name);
}


$user_id =  $userinfo[0]; 
$user_name =  $userinfo[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller use below code, no need to call the model function twice

```
$user_info = $this->model_users->get_user_id_name($email);
$user_id = $user_info['user_id'];
$user_name = $user_info['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

so the one liner code can be

```
list($user_id,$user_name)=$this->model_users->get_user_id_name($email); // now you can use $user_id and $user_name
```